# Node JS Express-validator - use 'check' only IF condition is true

Tags: node.js, express-validator

I am applying Node JS Express-validator. I need 'check' to work only if a condition is true.

I could do the following - it works fine. But is there a way of doing the same using purely Express-validator syntax ?

```
exports.type_create_post = [

    check('infotype').custom((infotype, { req }) => {
      if ( infotype == "webpage" ) {
        if (req.body.url.length>0 && !isURL(req.body.url)) return Promise.reject('Webpage is not valid');
        if (req.body.url.length==0) return Promise.reject('Webpage is required');
      }
      return Promise.resolve('valid');
    }),

(req, res, next) => {
```

Comment: Check the documentation of if condition in express validator. https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html#ifcondition